# Python-turtle syntax error in Sublime text editor 3

Tags: python-turtle

```
impor turtle
    sth=turtle.Turtle()

for i in range(30)
sth.forward(100)
sth,right(90)
turtle.done
```

The sublime text editor shows syntax error for**for i in `range(30)`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMDuu.png)

Answer (score 1):

`for i in range(3.4):
  print(i)`

you miss the `:` and the action to do.

use backquotes to format you code.